# C++: union that contains class it belongs to

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, unions

While this code is compiled without any error, I doubt that it will work as expected. Is such nesting allowed? I cannot use boost and c++17.

```
class Node;

typedef struct Value {      
    ValueTag type;

    union {         
        std::int32_t                          integerValue;
        std::float_t                          floatValue;
        bool                                  boolValue;
        std::vector<Node>                     arrayValue;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, Node> dictionaryValue;
    };          
} Value;

class Node {                
private:        
    Value m_value;          
public:                 
    virtual ~Node();    
};
```

Comment: unions dont handle constructors and destructors. so using a union with a non POD is unsafe (std::vector is unsafe). see std::variant and boost::variant

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you using `typedef struct...`? Structures are like classes, and the structure name is a type just like a class name.

Comment: Because I came from a C world.

Comment: `virtual ~Node();` is only necessary if your class will be used polymorphic. Otherwise you can remove the virtual (it adds overhead in the form of function pointers (vtable))

Answer (score 5):

> I doubt that it will work as expected.

You are correct. It won't. First, it won't actually compile if you ever try to construct a `Node`. You'll get something like:

```
prog.cc:26:10: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Node'
    Node n;
         ^
```

That's because in a `union`, any non-trivial operations are implicitly deleted. You will have to define `~Value()` to do the right thing. Which, assuming `type` is the index of which element in the union we actually are, to switch on that and call the appropriate destructor. And then do the same thing for copying and moving.

That said, the nesting of incomplete types is also not ok. `vector` is allowed to have an incomplete type as long as it's complete before first use. But `unordered_map` does not have this allowance. You will have to wrap the value type in something else - like `unique_ptr<Node>` or `shared_ptr<Node>`.

What you have in `Value` is a common pattern that has a million different names: discriminated union, sum type, or, perhaps most commonly, `variant`. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I suggest you instead use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (if you're using a recent enough compiler to support such a thing) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html) (otherwise). With that, you have:

```
using Value = variant<int32_t, float, bool,
    std::vector<Node>, std::unordered_map<std::string, Node>>;
```

and this type is already destructible, copyable, movable, and visitable for you.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**
My original answer was incorrect/misleading, plz ignore it. for the reason see the comments below. conside std::variant or boost::variant anyway :)

Non PlainOldData(POD) are unsafe in c-unions.

Especially for this proplem std::variant came into the c++17 standard. You could use boost::variant for earlier versions of C++.

The problem is, that union does not know anything about constructors and destructors. Therefore it is not possible to do more general things with elements of a union, that would be necessary (e.g. dynamic memory allocation)

Comment: You can very well make and use unions that contain non-trivial types. Redirecting to `boost::variant`/`std::variant` is wise, but the "not possible" is bogus. In any case, how the union is managed is unrelated to whether you can nest a class within itself through a `std::vector`.

Comment: ok. iam curious what works with non trivials? i think it is still wise to use std::variant for classes, isnt it?

Comment: Quentin, could you explain, how to use union with class members like vector or map in a right way

Comment: Everything works as usual, you just have to explicitly construct and destruct the active member. `std::variant` remains a better choice that manual management, yes.

Comment: I know, but I have no c++17 and cannot use boost for some reason.

Comment: @jonas_toth: You can use placement new and delete manually to manage it, which is a big headache and why we point at `std::variant` (with C++17) instead, which will do it all for you. Consider it a type-safe union.